# В Unity Hub не работает кнопка New

Tags: unity3d, unity-hub

в Unity Hub не работает кнопка New во вкладке Projects. хочу создать проект нажимаю на New кнопку и ничего просто ничего не происходит. Помогите пожалуйста с этим[image: введите сюда описание изображения]